# android.widget.Switch - on/off event listener?

Tags: android

I would like to implement a switch button, android.widget.Switch (available from API v.14).

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch" />
```

But I'm not sure how to add an event listener for the button. Should it be an "onClick" listener? And how would I know if it is toggled "on" or not?

Comment: OnClick via XML does actually work - but only for "clicks" on the button, not for "slides".

Answer (score 594, accepted):

Switch inherits `CompoundButton`'s attributes, so I would recommend the [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // do something, the isChecked will be
        // true if the switch is in the On position
    }
});
```

Comment: @Johan No trouble. I don't know about you but I wish they named it OnCheckChangedListener, similar to OnItemSelectedListener, since On-_Noun_-_Verb_-Listener is an established naming convetion.

Comment: But when you put the on a fragment for example, that thing always fires whenever you revisit the fragment if you set the switch to On.

Comment: @Sam What if I want to change the switch to ON or OFF state using method setChcked() method and don't want to execute the onCheckedChanged method? But when user again tap on switch method onCheckedChanged get executed... Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Buttons have `OnCLick`, switches do not have `OnChange`! Well designed Google team!

Comment: @deepakkumar fond any solution to switch on and off without executing onCheckChange?

Comment: @KZoNE What I did here is used the click listener to change the state & passed the switch to method(in my case API call) & then used the setChecked() method to change the state(like in onFailure/onError in API call). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 59):

Use the following snippet to add a Switch to your layout via XML:

```
<Switch
     android:id="@+id/on_off_switch"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textOff="OFF"
     android:textOn="ON"/>
```

Then in your Activity's onCreate method, get a reference to your Switch and set its OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
Switch onOffSwitch = (Switch)  findViewById(R.id.on_off_switch); 
onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Log.v("Switch State=", ""+isChecked);
}       

});
```

Comment: This is a more clear answer giving you the layout and code behind to match.

Comment: how to manage multiple switchcompat in the single listener ? Please suggest answer for that

Answer (score 45):

For those using Kotlin, you can set a listener for a switch (in this case having the ID `mySwitch`) as follows:

```kotlin
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    // do whatever you need to do when the switch is toggled here
}
```

`isChecked` is true if the switch is currently checked (ON), and false otherwise.

Answer (score 20):

Define your XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.neoecosystem.samplex.SwitchActivity">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create an Activity

```
public class SwitchActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    Switch mySwitch = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch);


        mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.myswitch);
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // do something when check is selected
        } else {
            //do something when unchecked
        }
    }

    ****
}
```

======== For **below API 14** use SwitchCompat =========

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.neoecosystem.samplex.SwitchActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class SwitchActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    SwitchCompat mySwitch = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch);


        mySwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.myswitch);
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // do something when checked is selected
        } else {
            //do something when unchecked
        }
    }
   *****
}
```

Comment: don't forget to check buttonView.isPressed()

Comment: @JacksOnF1re fine way to catch only user input, without programmatically establishment

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin:

```
        switch_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            // The switch enabled
            text_view.text = "Switch on"

        } else {
            // The switch disabled
            text_view.text = "Switch off"

        }
    }
```

Comment: this is fine for switch change , but how do you get current state ?

Comment: @Skovie Boolean state = switch_button.isChecked()

Answer (score 5):

The layout for Switch widget is something like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="All"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_toggle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the Activity class, you can code by two ways. Depends on the use you can code.

First Way

```
public class ActivityClass extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
Switch list_toggle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.return_vehicle);

    list_toggle=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.list_toggle);
    list_toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
}

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked) {
        list_toggle.setText("Only Today's");  //To change the text near to switch
        Log.d("You are :", "Checked");
    }
    else {
        list_toggle.setText("All List");   //To change the text near to switch
        Log.d("You are :", " Not Checked");
    }
}
```

Second way

```
public class ActivityClass extends Activity {
Switch list_toggle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.return_vehicle);

    list_toggle=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.list_toggle);
    list_toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          if(isChecked) {
             list_toggle.setText("Only Today's");  //To change the text near to switch
             Log.d("You are :", "Checked");
          }
          else {
             list_toggle.setText("All List");  //To change the text near to switch
             Log.d("You are :", " Not Checked");
          }
       }       
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**September 2020 - Programmatically Answer**

You can do it with programmatically for Switch Widget and Material Design:

```
Switch yourSwitchButton = findViewById(R.id.switch_id);

yourSwitchButton.setChecked(true); // true is open, false is close.

yourSwitchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
        if (b){
          //open job.
        }  
        else  {
          //close job.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use DataBinding and ViewModel for Switch Checked Change event

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="com.example.ui.ViewModel" />
    </data>
    <Switch
            android:id="@+id/on_off_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{(button, on) -> viewModel.onCheckedChange(on)}"
     />
```

Comment: android.widget.Switch does not have onCheckedChanged attirbute. 
You'll get error:
_AAPT: error: attribute android:onCheckedChanged not found._

Answer (score 1):

My solution, using a `SwitchCompat` and Kotlin. In my situation, i needed to react to a change only if the user triggered it through the UI. In fact, my switch reacts to a `LiveData`, and this made both `setOnClickListener` and `setOnCheckedChangeListener` unusable. `setOnClickListener` in fact reacts correctly to user interaction, but it's not triggered if the user drags the thumb across the switch. `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on the other end is triggered also if the switch is toggled programmatically (for example by an observer). Now in my case the switch was present on two fragments, and so onRestoreInstanceState would trigger in some cases the switch with an old value overwriting the correct value.

So, i looked at the code of SwitchCompat, and was able to mimic it's behaviour successfully in distinguishing click and drag and used that to build a custom touchlistener that works as it should. Here we go:

```
/**
 * This function calls the lambda function passed with the right value of isChecked
 * when the switch is tapped with single click isChecked is relative to the current position so we pass !isChecked
 * when the switch is dragged instead, the position of the thumb centre where the user leaves the
 * thumb is compared to the middle of the switch, and we assume that left means false, right means true
 * (there is no rtl or vertical switch management)
 * The behaviour is extrapolated from the SwitchCompat source code
 */
class SwitchCompatTouchListener(private val v: SwitchCompat, private val lambda: (Boolean)->Unit) :  View.OnTouchListener {
    companion object {
        private const val TOUCH_MODE_IDLE = 0
        private const val TOUCH_MODE_DOWN = 1
        private const val TOUCH_MODE_DRAGGING = 2
    }

    private val vc = ViewConfiguration.get(v.context)
    private val mScaledTouchSlop = vc.scaledTouchSlop
    private var mTouchMode = 0
    private var mTouchX = 0f
    private var mTouchY = 0f

    /**
     * @return true if (x, y) is within the target area of the switch thumb
     * x,y and rect are in view coordinates, 0,0 is top left of the view
     */
    private fun hitThumb(x: Float, y: Float): Boolean {
        val rect = v.thumbDrawable.bounds
        return x >= rect.left && x <= rect.right && y >= rect.top && y <= rect.bottom
    }

    override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (view == v) {
            when (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    val x = event.x
                    val y = event.y
                    if (v.isEnabled && hitThumb(x, y)) {
                        mTouchMode = TOUCH_MODE_DOWN;
                        mTouchX = x;
                        mTouchY = y;
                    }
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    val x = event.x
                    val y = event.y
                    if (mTouchMode == TOUCH_MODE_DOWN &&
                        (abs(x - mTouchX) > mScaledTouchSlop || abs(y - mTouchY) > mScaledTouchSlop)
                    )
                        mTouchMode = TOUCH_MODE_DRAGGING;
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                    if (mTouchMode == TOUCH_MODE_DRAGGING) {
                        val r = v.thumbDrawable.bounds
                        if (r.left + r.right < v.width) lambda(false)
                        else lambda(true)
                    } else lambda(!v.isChecked)
                    mTouchMode = TOUCH_MODE_IDLE;
                }
            }
        }
        return v.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

How to use it:

the actual touch listener that accepts a lambda with the code to execute:

```
myswitch.setOnTouchListener(
    SwitchCompatTouchListener(myswitch) {
        // here goes all the code for your callback, in my case
        // i called a service which, when successful, in turn would 
        // update my liveData 
        viewModel.sendCommandToMyService(it) 
    }
)
```

For the sake of completeness, this is how the observer for the state `switchstate` (if you have it) looked like:

```
switchstate.observe(this, Observer {
    myswitch.isChecked = it
})
```

Comment: Android team really should fix this... What I did instaed is in my LiveData observer, I unregister the onCheck, do my action, then set it back. This only works because UI changes happen on 1 thread (the main thread).

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways,

1. using xml onclick view
   Add Switch in XML as below:

   ```
   <Switch
   android:id="@+id/switch1"
   android:onClick="toggle"/>
   ```

In YourActivity Class (For E.g MainActivity.java)

```
    Switch toggle; //outside oncreate
    toggle =(Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1); // inside oncreate

    public void toggle(View view) //outside oncreate
    {
        if( toggle.isChecked() ){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                start.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.gold));
                stop.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                stop.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.gold));
                start.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        }
    }
```

2. using on click listener

Add Switch in XML as below:

In YourActivity Class (For E.g MainActivity.java)

```
    Switch toggle; // outside oncreate
    toggle =(Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);  // inside oncreate


    toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   // inside oncreate
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if( toggle.isChecked() ){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    start.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.gold));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    stop.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.gold));
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be used for all `CompoundButtons`. **Kotlin**

```
fun CompoundButton.onChecked(onChecked: (View, Boolean) -> Unit) {
    setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        onChecked(buttonView, isChecked)
    }
}
```