# android.widget.Switch toggled event listener?

Tags: android, adt

I have tried the code in the answer of [android-widget-switch-on-off-event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278507/android-widget-switch-on-off-event-listener), but the post doesn't say anything about the error I got trying to use it.

At the second line of the suggested code:

```
    switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangedListener() { //This line has the error
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            aTextView.setText("Switch was toggled");
        }
    });
```

This error triggers

> The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type CompoundButton is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCheckedChangedListener(){})

How can I fix this? All I want to do is call a function when the switch changes - as opposed to when it is clicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the listener to **this** because your class implements compoundbutton like so...

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Then add this method in your code...

```
    @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            boolean = isChecked;
            //whatever you want
        }
```

EDIT: if you havent implemented **CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangedListener** use this...

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

Comment: It still doesn't like that, it says "The method onCheckChangedListener(new onCheckChangedListener(){}) is undefined for the type Switch" does it matter that it is the type of switch available from api 14?

Comment: @grevin123 yeah that was wrong, see my new answer i updated it

Comment: Still not working, I must be putting it in the wrong place. Does your updated method go in any special place?

Comment: @grevin123 Ok wait, does your class implement CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: Yes, it then wants to make my activity abstract and it doesn't seem to help, is it OnCheckChacngedListener or OnCheckedChangeListener? Sorry, I'm very new to android dev

Comment: @grevin123 its onCheckedChangeListener

Comment: please follow the link http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-use-and-custom-switch-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look at http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-use-and-custom-switch-in-android.html

we can do this in given way

```
 switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (buttonView.isChecked()){
                                               //do something   }
                else{
                    //do something 
                }
            }
    });
```