# how to set visiblity in android for seekbar and textview

Tags: android

[image]

**There is a switch button , seek bar and text view in the above image
so when this activity starts . i want seek bar and the text view invisible by default 
and when i switch on the switch button , both seek bar and text view should be visible 
please provide a simple code for this operation .

i have tried using all gone ,visible and invisible stuffs . but it is not showing any effect.

**

Comment: put your code.. let us see.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like below?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find all view id here

    textview.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
    seekBar.setVisiblity(View.GONE);

    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // do something, the isChecked will be
            // true if the switch is in the On position
            if(isChecked){
              textview.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
              seekBar.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
              textview.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
              seekBar.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: what is compoundbutton actually ?

Comment: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener is on/off event listener for switch. check more detail here http://stackoverflow.com/q/11278507/1168654

Comment: When I wrote this ..and run it ..the activity does not run ..it shows unfortunately stopped ..when I remove this part of the code ..which you gave ..then it runs ..what to do ?

Comment: add our code back and get error logs from LOGCAT then post it in question