# Multiple Switch thumb images

Tags: android, android-switch

In Android, is it possible to have a `Switch` that can have different images set for the thumb's checked and unchecked states?

For example, when a `Switch` is in the unchecked state, I'd like the thumb to use `image_1.png` and when the `Switch` is in the checked state, I'd like the thumb to use `image_2.png`.

[image]

I used the following [guide](https://medium.com/@elye.project/customizing-switch-using-xml-ca0d37204a86) to set a `Switch`'s thumb to an image, but the image applies to both the checked and unchecked states, I'd like to have a separate image for both states.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using a tag that is meant for iOS. I changed it in my suggested edit.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278528/6214491), you can do something like the following:

```
yourSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // Set to image_2.png
            yourSwitch.setThumbResource(image2); // <-- Using an image from drawable
        } else {
            // Set to image_1.png
            yourSwitch.setThumbResource(image1);
        }
    }
});
```

And if you need to convert your `Switch` to programmatic form:

```
Switch yourSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.yourSwitch);
```